# Grid layout rendered differently on refresh vs. resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-grid

I just started with a grid layout and noted that it renders differently on the same viewport size:

(1) Initial display in maximized window, nothing special here:
[image]

(2) After resizing the browser window using [image] button the text in the left sidebar gets wrapped:
[image]

(3) After refreshing the browser window without changing its size, the wrapping in the left sidebar is removed:
[image]
**Note how there suddenly is no more wrapping in the text in the left sidebar, while the viewport size is still the same!**

**How can that be?** I am on Windows with Chrome 89.0.4389.82 (latest stable). With Firefox 86 I also have strange resizing effects (wrapping text on small windows and the wrapping does not get removed on maximize). Wondering of two major browser can have bugs on simple grids? Am I doing something wrong/missing?

Used CSS/HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr);
  }

  header {
    background-color: #add790;
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }

  nav {
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
  }

  article {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
  }
</style>

<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <p>Navigation</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
</nav>
<article>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
</article>
```

**Update**: With added `nav > p { min-width: max-content; }` rule:

after resizing the window:
[image]
after hitting refresh:
[image]
Note the red marked gap between the text and the scrolling bar.

**Update 2:** with `width: fit-content;` for nav:
before refresh:
[image]
after refresh:
[image]
so the navbar stays exactly the same size, but the main content position is shifted.

Comment: I have the same bug on Chromium 89, and don't have it on Chrome 89 and Firefox 86 (on linux). This only happens with the resize button and not when resizing it with the mouse. So it's probably just a bug.

Comment: @RomanMkrtchian Thanks, I was also thinking about it being a bug. Just wondering that it exists in Firefox and Chrome on such a - I would say - basic example. Let's see if at least someone here has an idea for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

nothing strange, the first column is set to `auto` (`grid-template-columns: auto ...`) so as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) it will behave like this:

> auto
>
> As a maximum represents the largest max-content size of the items in that track.
> As a minimum represents the largest minimum size of items in that track (specified by the min-width/min-height of the items). This is
> often, though not always, the min-content size.
> If used outside of minmax() notation, auto represents the range between the minimum and maxium described above. This behaves similarly
> to min-content(min-content,max-content) in most cases.

the "quirks" are fixed easily by css rule `nav > p { min-width: max-content; }`

Before digging any further into the details, a note about environment:

> **OS:** Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
>
> **Browser-1:** Firefox 85.0.1 (64-bit)
>
> **Browser-2:** Chromium Version 89.0.4389.72 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

**Listing all scenarios:**

> 1a. initial maximized `window`
>
> 1b. initial maximized `iframe`
>
> 2a. initial minimized `window`
>
> 2b. initial minimized `iframe`
>
> 3a. maximize `window`
>
> 3b. maximize `iframe`
>
> 4a. minimize `window`
>
> 4b. minimize `iframe`
>
> 5 . `overflow: scroll` (in place of `overflow: auto`, in all above scenarios)

**`max-content`** behavior related to scenarios:

> 1. **Chromium**
>
>    fixes wrapping in (`4b`)
>
>    no effect in (`5`)
> 2. **Firefox**
>
>    fixes wrapping in (`2a`, `2b`, `3a`, `3b`, `4a`, `4b`)
>
>    no effect in (`5`)

**`padding`** issue in `nav` related to scenarios:

> 1. **Chromium**
>
>    no right padding in (`4b`)
>
>    double right padding in (`3a`, `3b`), i.e. CSS padding `1em` + scrollbar width `~17px`
>
>    no issues in (`5`)
> 2. **Firefox**
>
>    no right padding in (`2a`, `2b`, `3a`, `3b`, `4a`, `4b`)
>
>    no issues in (`5`)

Can be observed that issues are absent in scenario (`5`), i.e. when scrollbar is always visible, though this solution is not very appealing.
Considering all the above, the explanation of different behavior between `load` vs `resize` could be the following:

> 1. On `load`, since the size of window is known and nothing is rendered yet, content (width+padding+scroll+border) is accommodated
>    recursively as many times as needed till fits the geometry with
>    minimal performance penalties.
> 2. On `resize`, when content is already on screen, subsequent layout shifts are rendered in frames to accommodate the new geometry (note
>    that application resize is a feature controlled by OS, not to be
>    confused with `window` `resize`), so during resize, when browser
>    engine detects an overflow, the container `nav` may have no enough
>    space to fit scrollbar, and although there is plenty of space in the
>    adjacent container, to avoid a reflow avalanche (which require
>    considerable processing resources and lack of these cause visual
>    artifacts), the space for scrollbar is taken from that context.

Which means that it is very unlikely to fix the issue with CSS alone, since it doesn't offer any control over that, nor this behavior will be fixed in browsers any soon, so the only solution we have is to deal with this using javascript.
The most obvious solution is to listen to `resize` event on `window` and trigger further a content reflow, for this simple layout here, toggling `overflow: initial` in place of `overflow: auto` is enough, more complex layouts could require more aggressive styles like `width: 0 !important`, for ultimate control a `resize observer` could be used on specific targets, triggering reflow only in that context.

With these conclusions put together, a workaround which fix all the scenarios above (in my environment*), is next:

> 1. Add CSS rule **`nav > p { min-width: max-content; }`**
> 2. Add CSS rule **`.reflowing * { overflow: initial; }`**
> 3. Attach **`resize`** event listener on window which will toggle the class `.reflowing` on `document.body` for a period long enough to
>    generate a content reflow, one `requestAnimationFrame` (~16ms) seems
>    to be enough here.

- **Note:** this fixes completely Chromium, Firefox will still have the issue with padding which require more hacks, since it seems that it's scrollbar is only an overlay for scrollable element.

**The implementation:**

```js
const initReflow = el => requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    el.classList.add('reflowing');
    requestAnimationFrame(() => el.classList.remove('reflowing'));
});
addEventListener('resize', () => initReflow(document.body));
```

```css
body {
    background: white;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr);
}

header {
    background-color: #add790;
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: span 2;
}

nav {
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

article {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav > p {
    min-width: max-content;
}
.reflowing * {
    overflow: initial;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <p>Navigation</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
</nav>
<article>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
</article>
```

**Resources:**

[Windowing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system)

[Compositing window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager)

[Multiple buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering)

[How browsers work](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm)

[CSS block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

[CSS overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

**Disclaimer:** the above conclusions were not drawn from scientific or specialized materials, but general purpose resources, also personal experience, so they should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: thank for your reply, but in the mentioned documentation I can't see the reason why the observed behaviour should be correct. I applied your fix and tested it, it doesn't work though: refreshing still changes the layout. See the edit in my original question ):

Comment: yeah, the docs may seem abstract, in my interpretation `auto` is first candidate to shrink on minimize and last candidate to grow on maximize. If about different behavior, then most probably that it is because on refresh layout is calculated from scratch but on resize only the delta, at least in Chrome seems to be so, but this again is over-simplistic, a more comprehensive material on this topic is here: [IHow browsers work](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm)

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry that this is a longer description. It is not easy to describe the 'WHY' even there are a different behaviors between Chrome and Firefox and once more different browser events with different behaviors within the browsers itself.*

**SHORT: THE REASON**

The reason for the 'strange' behavior is the (different) way the browser auto calculates width of columns  using `auto` in grids or tables. But what you see is the (by the browser coders) intended behavior of the browsers. Yes: that can make someone crazy... ;-)

**LONGER: WHY / what happens?**

**General base:** In your example the `auto width` of navigation column is calculated on the widest element: the word 'Navigation'. Check it yourself: the width of the Navbar changes when you i.e. make second element longer using text 'Some text more words'.

**Explanation behavior in Chrome**

On full screen the window is height enough so the navigation doesn't need a vertical scrollbar. Using the window button makes window less high so the content in the navbar has a vertical overflow. The Browser now adds the vertical scrollbar ... the scrollbar takes place in the navigational section ... but as of unknown reason Chrome does not add to that event a recalculation off the auto width. The scrollbar is just added to the navigational section. And as for this there now is less place for the content the content wraps. (Note: the word 'Navigation' cannot wrap and now reaches into the padding. So it only seemes there is enough place, - but it isn't.)

When you now reload the page, it is another browser event. You load the page from start and the browser calculates the auto-width from start. In this case he detects from the beginning that the scrollbar is needed and the auto-width calculation in Chrome includes the width off the scrollbar to the width of the navigational section.

You are able to observe that when reloading in this situation: the navigation section becomes slightly wider.

**Explanation behavior in Firefox (slightly different)**

On full screen in Firefox it's the same as in Chrome. Enough height for navigation so no vertical scrollbar. Using the window button to shrink the window in Firefox is nearly the same as in Chrome: adding the now needed vertical scrollbar to navigation and no obvious recalculation of auto-width. But there still seems to be a recalculation as Firefox additional adds a horizontal scrollbar when he recognized the content of the navigation section is wider than the auto-width-space.

The big difference is the reload event now. Same like in Chrome: Firefox ('re-')calculates the auto-width. But in Firefox nothing changes ... that is because Firefox calculates auto-width always without scrollbars and only adds it to the inner space container ... ugly ... but it's the way it is.

**Check that behavior yourself when resizing height off window**

You are able to confirm that if you use another browser event: just resize window height by tracking the window edges with the mouse. On that event both browsers do a recalculation of auto-width. If the new height makes navigation bar scrolling Chrome adds the scrollbar and makes navigation section wider. Firefox adds scrollbar but place it inner to the navigation section which means width of navigation sections remains the same.

Note: It is easier to observe the effect if you remove some lines of content in navigation section.

**SHORT POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

3 CORRECTIONS ONLY**

1. Add `15px` extra padding to navigation section so Firefox has enough space to place the scrollbar.
2. Change overflow to `overflow-y: auto` and `overflow-x: hidden` to avoid possible horizontal scrollbar in Firefox
3. Avoid unwanted wrapping of the navigation elements. In your case you have inline content (normal text in `p` elements). Just add `nav > p { white-space: nowrap }`. Now the text cannot wrap and auto-width-calculation takes the widest text element. You can check it if you now add more words to one of your elements in the navigation, i.e. `<p>Some text with more words.</p>`.

:::
A long explanation but ...
three corrections ONLY ...
THAT'S ALL!!!

See example.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr);
}

header {
  background-color: #add790;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

nav {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-right: calc(1em + 15px);  // added space scrollbar Firefox
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
nav > p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

article {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <p>Navigation</p>
    <p>Some text with more words.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
</nav>
<article>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
</article>
```

---

*Updated: Corection in description off solution. Changed mistook values for overflow-Y/-X. In example they had been correct.*

**UPDATED CODE**
Corrected the paddings set to navigational section (marked in the code) as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: sadly, it wont fix the right padding issue for my Chromium on Ubuntu, also in Firefox a new issue is popped, the `p` content overflows when window is minimized, so it would be cut if there will be a `overflow: hidden` rule

Comment: Sorry to insist: What you asked is as old as auto-sizing is used (first on tables) to realize this layout in early times of web. Same now for grid-layouts. Yes: the behavior of the different browsers is confusing. What you see is the traditional (tested) standard solution to handle the different behaviors for that type of layout. Please have a nearer look to that solution: `overflow-X` IS SET to `hidden`! THAT IS INTENDED TO HANDLE THE LAYOUT. Together with `auto-width` and `white-space: no-wrap` EXACTLY THIS EFFECTS: the section stay open so content-section only floats. For sure NOTHING cuts!

Comment: @syduki: Please let’s stay to your original Question. Ubuntu was not part of it … and you didn’t mention other additional padding problems than the asked/shown behaviors in the navigational area. Responsive was not part of it as well. Traditional handling are / could be: moving navigation to the left out of sight, making navigation items smaller (i.e. by using symbols) or using a mobile menu. Help is possible. But to be honest: all that is not part of your actual question.

Comment: I just shared my observations, as after some 20+ years of browsers development we still have to fiddle with such browsers specific implementation issues, and we don't have at least some rudimentary universal solution.

Comment: an BTW, out of curiosity I just tested it your approach on Windows 10 (Version 1803 OS Build 17134.1845) and Chromium (Version 91.0.4442.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)) and it doesn't solve the issue either, the right padding is still there.

Comment: Oh … that’s great ( it is really!!! meant that way!) … So we are all old hands knowing the typical challenges and changing tasks of web development within the times. Your question is really one off the few remained problems caused by different browser behaviors if I compare it to the time of IE<=6 and former times Opera and Netscape (before Firefox) ... I like such specialties. Thx to Chromium there are not too many differences left … :-)

Comment: @syduki: ok ... I've got your feedback to the coding. But to be honest: I cannot confirm it here. Based on the expected browser behaviors and the settings I don't have it here in the actual browser versions (Chrome/Firefox) on windows 10 ... there is an intended padding left added to the navigation section to handle the Firefox behavior? ... or (sorry!) I really do not get what padding do you mean.

Comment: Maybe I have found the padding you asked for: the extra padding needed for FF behavior has been set to all egdes of navigational section. I corrected it to right edge only. It is marked in the code (`calc()` expression). The padding right is intended to grant enough space to the right auto scrollbar which FF adds inner in the navigation box without making the section wider.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that the `width` is not mentioned for the `nav` and hence it is behaving differently on resize and refresh.

So, what I did is adding `width: fit-content;` for `nav`

```
nav {
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    width: fit-content;
  }
```

This solved the issue. You can check the full html snipped below:

```html
<html><head><style type="text/css">
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr);
  }

  header {
    background-color: #add790;
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }

  nav {
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    width: fit-content;
  }

  article {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
  }
</style>

</head><body><header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <p>Navigation</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
</nav>
<article>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
</article></body></html>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. This indeed works for the navbar, but leads to a new issue with the main content right to it. See my Update 2 in my question. Any idea? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the **scrollbar** leaves behind a **width**. And this is very strange. I'm sure this is a *bug*.

If you set `overflow: overlay` instead of `overflow: auto` in `nav`, and do the procedure with window siding, then you will see that the problem (bug) is `overflow: auto`.

I made a solution to your problem. And I cannot say that this solution is a *crutch*.

This solution consists in *updating* the content of the `<nav>` tag, thereby returning this tag to its **default width**.

Just use this code by pasting it into your **js** file, or inside a `<script>` tag:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    let nav = document.querySelector("nav");
    let nav_content = nav.innerHTML;
    nav.innerHTML = nav_content;
};
```

Comment: this approach doesn't have any advantage over pure CSS reflow, it has the same effect - to trigger a reflow, but with a big performance impact since the whole DOM tree would be removed and recreated, moreover, it is not suitable for any kind of modern web applications

Comment: @syduki, **1.** *"since the whole DOM tree would be removed and recreated"* - what?? :)) **2.** In your opinion, the size of the output nav element and the size of the full DOM tree are the same? It’s strange. **3.** *"it is not suitable for any kind of modern web applications"* - Are you serious, mate? You have a good sense of humor :)

Comment: 1. yes. 2. yes, the `nav` element has it's own DOM tree, there are many `p` element in that tree, go open DevTools and take a look what happens there when you are changing `innerHTML`. 3. can you use this "solution" in a `React`, `Vue`, `Angular`, etc? think again

Comment: @syduki, This is one way to update nav. Yes, let's say my solution is a crutch, but it works. I guess the OP will not have to constantly resize the window. In one of the comments the OP wrote - *Let's see if at least someone here has an idea for a workaround*. And I gave a solution. Moreover, I have indicated the reason for the bug. Also, the OP did not mention the work of his project on js frameworks. Please tell me, did your answer help solve the problem?

Comment: *"OP will not have to constantly resize the window"* - with this solution it is enough to resize one time only to break any application that rely on VirtualDOM, and in many cases those without VirtualDOM too. Yes, there is not a mention about framework, but does it means that question was about a solution which work only in pure HTML sites? You may read my answer, I've said there everything.

Comment: @syduki, *with this solution it is enough to resize one time only to break any application that rely on VirtualDOM* - omG. Did I mention somewhere that this is a solution for **any** application? No! You are exaggerating too much. Ok. How can you solve the bug indicated by the OP? Would you advise?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov: Had a nearer look to your solution. A very interesting technique I did not know yet. Quite simple. And a good idea to actualize content to trigger a re-rendering in the browser. For sure not to use only in such a situation. Thx for this suggestion … that’s what I am here for :-)

Answer (score -1):

See if this code works to your liking

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr);
  }

  header {
    background-color: #add790;
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }

  nav {
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  article {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  article::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <p>Navigation</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
</nav>
<article>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
</article>
```